# STM32F1 GPIO registers LED not blinking, just staying on whole time

Tags: stm32, gpio, led

I'm starting my journey with microcontrollers and I'm getting my way with STM32F1 (Nucleo board with STM32F103RB). I try to learn writing using registers and it looks like I'm stuck with first 'task' - blinking led. I managed to turn led on, but I can't make it blink. What's strange, when I go to debug (I work on Keil uVision) and look into GPIOA peripheral, port 5 (led is PA5) has this tick going on and off which means it should blink in reality. But is not. I tried changing delay and nothing happens. I'm stuck.
What am I doing wrong?
Here's my code:

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"
void delay(unsigned int ms){
    unsigned int i, j;
        for(i = 0; i < ms; i++)
            for(j = 0; j < 20000; j++);
}
int main(void){
  RCC->APB2ENR |= (1<<2);
    
  GPIOA->CRL |= (   (1<<21));
  GPIOA->CRL &= ~(  (1<<22) | (1<<23) | (1<<20) );
    
  while(1){
  GPIOA->BSRR |= (1<<5);
  delay(200);
  GPIOA->BSRR |= (1<<21);
  delay(200);
    
    
    }
    
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Are you sure that your `delay` function lasts for 200 ms?

Comment: Also note that the `BSRR` register is write only. Thus the bitwise *or* operation has undefined behavior. Just use `GPIOA->BSRR = (1<<5)`.

Comment: You can check the GPIOA->BSRR commands by steping through you code with Keil. This will remove the possible missbehaviour of the delay function as mentioned by others.

Answer (score 0):

As dunajski put it, are you sure that you delay function delays for 200ms? Or to put it more directly: Dont ever use NOPs as a delay. This might work in some specific cases on a specific chip/system but you can assume it just won't delay anything. NOP-loops will be optimized out depending on the compiler. And even if not will have different runtimes on different frequencies/architectures.

Use `sleep()` or `usleep()` instead if you just want delay. This will 'block' the controller for the time, so you cant do anything in the meantime but for your testing, this will suffice. Use some systick callback (or interrupts) if you want concurrent timing.

Answer (score 0):

After enabling the clock you need to wait this operation to propagate over the bus. It can be archived by using the barrier instruction or readback from the register.

Do not use magic numbers. USE definitions from CMSIS. Check if set the correct mode.

This is invalid:

```
GPIOA->BSRR |= (1<<5); // Set bit 5
delay(200); // delay some time
GPIOA->BSRR |= (1<<21); // Set bit 21 (not 5)
```

BSRR is **write only** and you should not read from it.

```
GPIOA->BSRR = (1<<5); // Set bit 5
delay(200); // delay some time
GPIOA->BSRR = (1<<21); // Set bit 21 (not 5)
```

If you want to use loops for delays do it a different way:

```
void delay(unsigned int ms)
{
    unsigned int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < ms; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < 20000; j++)
            asm(":::memory");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6c8dqKT8P

Your function will be optimized out to the single return if you enable optimizations.

https://godbolt.org/z/szfT7Tfv9